# Radioactive objects in a student's room

Tags: everyday-life, home-experiment, radioactivity

Contrary to common believe, radioactive materials are everywhere, including inside our bodies, our food, the air we breathe and so on.

From [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_radiation#Food_and_water) (emphasis mine):

> The decay of a <sup>14</sup>C atom inside DNA in one person happens about **50**
>   times **per second**, changing a carbon atom to one of nitrogen.

With an average life of 80 years a person would have about 10<sup>11</sup> such decays, or 100,000,000,000. Thats a lot of damaged DNA.

While trying to explain to my students that ionizing radiation is something natural that our body can (usually) cope with, I started wondering..

**Question:**
Can you give a few notable examples of radioactive objects inside a student's room? The student included.

To narrow it down a bit:
Assume a typical room of a teen (a pc, carpets, bed, sheets, his watch, food on his desk). By objects I am not referring to the building materials of his room, neither the air.

Comment: Obbiously you have to check [this xkcd chart](http://xkcd.com/radiation/)!

Comment: My guess,the walls, if they are solid stone or brick.

Comment: Alpha emitter in fire alarm?

Comment: @Bosoneando Very interesting chart, but i have seen it before. By the way, if my question feels like it suggests that this amount of radiation is dangerous let me know so that i can edit accordingly.

Comment: The radium on the face of his old alarm clock. And of course the tritium in his gunsights. LOL!

Comment: I think the only thing wrong with this is using the metric "Bq/g" since then obviously the answer is a single stray atom of something highly unstable. Asking about dominant sources of radiation regardless of mass, however, is very important. As anyone who's ever worked in a radiation lab can tell you, the experimenter emits enough radiation to throw off numerous experiments.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I think this problem can be avoided if we consider as object the whole ... "object". Eg. not only the paint of a radium painted watch, rather divide by the whole object's mass. I dont mind removing that though, besides i only added it after seeing 2 close votes in an effort to narrow it.

Comment: I guess as long as some sensible definition of "whole object" is understood it should be fine. Honestly, the answer is either "living tissue" or "the walls" if you include them depending on what the room is made of. To first order all living tissue is the same, the popular imagination's thoughts about bananas notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the air because of the Radon:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon#Domestic-level_exposure

Comment: This does little to actually address the question. How does this relate to the other objects in a typical bedroom?